# Get full html div text

Tags: android, parsing, web-scraping, dart, flutter

I'm trying to parse an Html page and i need to get the full `div`:

```
void printing() async {
   http.Response response = await http.get('https://stackoverflow.com/');// example

   Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

   var elent = document.getElementById('content') ;

   print(elent);

}
```

the result is:

```
I/flutter ( 2336): <html div>
```

how can i print all html elements inside `div` ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html package allows you to query elements similar to what you can do in the browser (for example `querySelectorAll()`).

> ```
> import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
> import 'package:html/dom.dart';
>
> main() {
>   var document = parse(
>       '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
>   print(document.outerHtml);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you 'outerHtml' is the one i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

We are writing at the same time me and Gunter ^^

As Gunter pointed out you can use the Dart package html.

- https://github.com/dart-lang/html
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html#-installing-tab-

In your `pubspec.yaml` you sould import it:

```
html: ^0.13.3+3
```

Imports should look like that if you have errors in duplication of `Text` in `dom.dart` and `widgets.dart`.

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' hide Text;
```

and then you can givin it a try like this:

```
void _printing() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get('https://stackoverflow.com/'); // example

    Document document = parse(response.body);

    var element = document.getElementById('content');

    debugPrint(element.querySelectorAll('div').toString());
  }
```

with `querySelectorAll` you get all selectors of the page:

[image]

And then you can loop through all of them:

```
element.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((value) {
      debugPrint(value.outerHtml);
    });
```

Comment: `debugPrint(element.outerHtml);`

Comment: @FatimaTiwTiwSubscribe Said that becouse you have written "how can i print all div elements ?". I've misunderstood it. Did you mean all elements inside the outer div one? Anyway hope you have found it helpful, also for the imports section highlight. And if you need to loop or have a more deep query  on selectors you need to use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Doesn't mind. You're welcome ;-]. No hard feelings for that of course. Enjoy coding!